# Django: call index function on page reload

Tags: python, django, url-routing

I was wondering how to call my `index(request)` function thats in `views.py` upon every page reload.  Currently `index(request)` only gets called when the app originally loads.  Every other page reload after that calls another function in `views.py` called `filter_report(request)`.  The problem I am running into is that 85% of the code in `filter_report(request)` is also in `index(request)` and from my understanding you don't really want 2 functions that do a lot of the same stuff.  What I would like to do is take that 15% of code that isn't in `index(request)` but is in `filter_report(request)` and split it into different methods and just have `index(request)` call those other methods based on certain conditionals.

Comment: I would suggest posting the code you do have on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that really is not how it works. Each view is separate and is only called from the URLs that map to it. If you have shared code, you probably want to either factor it out into separate functions that you can call from each view, or use something like a template tag or context processor to add the relevant information to the template automatically.

Comment: Okay, I originally thought I could just call `index` from `filter_report` and pass it the necessary information.  However, I ran into an error based around parameters because upon the original page load index isn't being passed any of the other stuff that `filter_report` would pass it.  So are you suggesting taking the shared code and putting it into a separate function that both `index` and `filter_report` call?